# How to fix "cannot find -lxml2" error while installing 'igraph' for python?

Tags: software-installation, python, xml

On Ubuntu 15.04 I am trying to install 'igraph' using the following command:

```
pip install python-igraph
```

in order to, well, use the `igraph` package in python to work with graphs and stuff. However, the installation fails with the following output

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2357: recipe for target 'libigraph.la' failed
make[3]: *** [libigraph.la] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/tmp/pip-build-8dtEwd/python-igraph/tmp/igraph.dZXTk4/igraph-0.7.1/src'
Makefile:1377: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/pip-build-8dtEwd/python-igraph/tmp/igraph.dZXTk4/igraph-0.7.1/src'
Makefile:480: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/pip-build-8dtEwd/python-igraph/tmp/igraph.dZXTk4/igraph-0.7.1'
Makefile:382: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Extracting igraph-0.7.1.tar.gz...
Configuring igraph...
Could not download and compile the C core of igraph.
```

`libxml2` seems to be installed (i.e. a `apt-get install libxml2` does not install anything), so how to fix those issues?

I probably will code my own graph class anyway as I suspect this to be faster than to fix the above problems...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`libxml2` is the runtime shared library, suitable for running already-compiled programs that use that library.  If you want to compile programs that use `libxml2`, you need to install `libxml2-dev`.

This is true for most library packages on ubuntu (and debian, mint, etc. RH and others have similar conventions) - `libfoo` is the runtime shared library, `libfoo-dev` contains the development headers and .a archive

For libz, the package is `zlib1g-dev`

BTW, `python-igraph` 0.6.5-1 is packaged for debian - are you sure it's not also pre-packaged for ubuntu?  If it is, you're much better off installing the ubuntu package.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your help fixed the problem. I wonder how you guys always know what to install? I mean the mapping from the library to the name of the thing to be installed with `apt-get`: 'libxml2' -> 'libxml2-dev' und 'libz' -> 'zlib1g-dev'. This is not logical. This is also the reason, why I cannot install the python library via `agt-get` since I do not know the name of the thing to install...

Comment: @Alex `-dev` packages contain the header files, which you need to compile against when building using a library. At least for C and C++. That's a standard Unix naming convention, I think. And `apt-get install python-igraph`.

Comment: `apt-cache search` is your friend

Comment: Also, for unusual cases like zlib1g that don't fit the common pattern, I know i have `libz.so.*` so I can use `dpkg -S libz.so` or `dlocate libz.so` or other search tools to find out which package it belongs too (zlib1g).  From that, I can guess that the dev package is likely to be `zlib1g-dev`, or run `apt-cache search -n zlib1g` and that will tell me that `zlib1g`, `zlib1g-dev`, and `zlib1g-dbg` (dev pkg with debugging symbols left in) all exist.

Comment: Finally, on debian (and ubuntu, etc), python libraries tend to be named `python-foo`.  `apt-cache search python foo` will usually find them.  Perl libraries, OTOH, tend to be named `libfoo-perl`.